# JSF ViewState not updated when submitting 2 forms

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, mojarra

I have a though issue with JSF 2. I use Mojarra 2.1.14 with Primefaces 3.1.4

I have a page with 2 forms : **formA** and **formB**. The two forms contains each the ViewState in an hidden input field.

```
<h:form id="formA" binding="#{sessionBean.formA}">
    <h:commandButton value="formA" action="#{sessionBean.actionA}">
        <f:ajax/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form id="formB" binding="#{sessionBean.formB}">
    <h:commandButton value="formB" action="#{sessionBean.actionB}">
        <f:ajax/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

User submits **formA** with an Ajax action. Inside the Java action I update explicitly **formA** and **formB** (which are binded).

```
public void actionA(){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(formA.getClientId());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(formB.getClientId());
    System.out.println("action A!!");
}

public void actionB(){
    System.out.println("action B!!");
}
```

In the Ajax responses there is the HTML code for **formA** and **formB** ( element) and the ViewState.

JSF updates the HTML of **formA** and **formB** and set the ViewState of the calling form : **formA**.  **formB** do not contains any ViewState.

User submit **formB** with an Ajax action. Because ViewState is not defined, postBack is false and the renderResponse is set to true in the RESTORE phase, skipping the INVOKE APPLICATION phase: the action is not called. After the response VIEW_STATE is updated and if user sumbit **formB**, the action is called.

Is it a JSF 2 bug or limitation? Or Do I do something wrong ?

You can find a maven projet on GitHub:
https://github.com/nithril/jsf-multiple-form

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you post a code for those two forms, and AJAX update attributes?

Comment: I'm about to finish a small maven project

Comment: Try to add explicitly `render=":formB"` inside `f:ajax` tag.

Comment: It's works but I do not understand yet why it is different from the getRenderIds().add(formB.getClientId());

In fact the two forms are in 2 xhtml file fragment which do not see each other. Only the parent component see the 2 forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem you are facing is connected with known issue with JSF JavaScript library. Workaround is to explicitly set client id of another form in `rendered` attribute of `f:ajax` tag:

```
<h:form id="formA" binding="#{sessionBean.formA}">
  <h:commandButton value="formA" action="#{sessionBean.actionA}">
    <f:ajax render=":formB @form"/>
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form id="formB" binding="#{sessionBean.formB}">
  <h:commandButton value="formB" action="#{sessionBean.actionB}">
    <f:ajax render=":formA @form"/>
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

More about this:

- [Ajax rendering of content which contains another form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm)
- [javax.faces.ViewState is missing after ajax render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830795/javax-faces-viewstate-is-missing-after-ajax-render)
- [Rendering other form by ajax causes its view state to be lost, how do I add this back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807334/rendering-other-form-by-ajax-causes-its-view-state-to-be-lost-how-do-i-add-this)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The 2 xhtml forms are loosely coupled. Sadly, to correct this issue I must strongly coupled the two.

Comment: On first link there is a JavaScript code which may fix this, maybe you should try with it first. You are using primefaces, so it should work. Knowing BalusC's approach that probably work.

Comment: I have test the BalusC script and it works. I use primefaces but it do not correct the case where component is refreshed using Java

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative trick if you use MyFaces 2.0.x / 2.1.x that will update the forms correctly, adding the following script:

```
window.myfaces = window.myfaces || {};
myfaces.config = myfaces.config || {};
//set the config part
myfaces.config.no_portlet_env = true;
```

See [JSF Ajax and Multiple Forms](http://www.irian.at/en/blog/-/blogs/jsf-ajax-and-multiple-forms).

This option is a lot better because you don't need to worry about fix every place in your webapp where you use multiple forms, just add it to the main template and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I should give a try with myfaces